# Why is my Rails hidden_field not picking up any value when all other fields work fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, hidden-field

I have a model for a "timeline_event" which belongs_to a sales_opportunity. For example it could be "call the prospect" or similar, with a due_date, activity_details (optional), and a checkbox to say whether it's complete or not. This works fine. I can add new timeline_events to the database via a modal on the sales_opportunity page, which also works fine. However when I try to edit the timeline_event (via the timeline_events edit controller action) the hidden_field for sales_opportunity_id refuses to pick up the value (it has no value whatsoever). Even when I try to force a value:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :sales_opportunity_id, :value => @sales_opportunity.id %>
```

It won't add any value to the hidden_field. I've tried moving the field around within the form group, but nothing seems to work. I have other forms that are similar in my model that work fine, but for some reason this isn't working - can anyone help please?

My Form:

```
<%= form_for(@timeline_event, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.hidden_field :sales_opportunity_id %>
        <%= f.label :activity, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
        <div class ="col-md-8">
          <%= f.text_field :activity, :placeholder => "Enter activity details" %>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <%= f.label :due_date, :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
            <div class ="col-md-8">
             <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker' data-date-format="YY.MM.DD">
                 <%= f.text_field :due_date, class: "form-control", data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD' }, :placeholder => "YYYY/MM/DD" %>
                 <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                 </span>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :event_notes, 'Activity Details', :class => "col-md-4 control-label" %>
          <div class ="col-md-8">
            <%= f.text_area(:event_notes, :placeholder => "Put any notes about the activity here") %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
          <div class="checkbox input">
              <label>
              <%= f.check_box :completed %> Task Completed?
              </label>
           </div>
           <br>
         </div>
       <%= @sales_opportunity.id %>
       <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
      <% end %>
```

*Note - I include the line <%= @sales_opportunity.id %> here and this does output the correct sales_opportunity_id for the timeline_event. All other fields (activity, due_date, completed) are populated with the information of the timeline_event I'm trying to edit.

Timeline_Events_Controller:

```
class TimelineEventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_timeline_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :index]
  before_action :correct_org,   only: [:edit, :update, :show, :index]

  # GET /timeline_events
  # GET /timeline_events.json
  def index
    @timeline_events = TimelineEvent.all
  end

  # GET /timeline_events/1
  # GET /timeline_events/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /timeline_events/new
  def new
    @timeline_event = TimelineEvent.new(sales_opportunity_id: params[:sales_opportunity_id])
  end

  # GET /timeline_events/1/edit
  def edit
    @timeline_event = TimelineEvent.find(params[:id])
    @sales_opportunity = @timeline_event.sales_opportunity
  end

  # POST /timeline_events
  # POST /timeline_events.json
  def create
    @timeline_event = TimelineEvent.new(timeline_event_params)
    @sales_opportunity = @timeline_event.sales_opportunity

respond_to do |format|
  if @timeline_event.save
    format.html { redirect_to @timeline_event.sales_opportunity, :flash => {:success =>  'Timeline event was successfully created.'} }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @timeline_event }
    format.js
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @timeline_event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js { render json: @sales_opportunity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

  # PATCH/PUT /timeline_events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /timeline_events/1.json
  def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @timeline_event.update(timeline_event_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @timeline_event.sales_opportunity, :flash => {:success =>  'Timeline event was successfully updated.'} }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @timeline_event }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @timeline_event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

  # DELETE /timeline_events/1
  # DELETE /timeline_events/1.json
  def destroy
    @timeline_event.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to timeline_events_url, :flash => {:success =>  'Timeline event was successfully destroyed.'} }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
 # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
 def set_timeline_event
  @timeline_event = TimelineEvent.find(params[:id])
 end


def timeline_event_params
  params.require(:timeline_event).permit(:sales_opportunity_id, :due_date, :activity, :completed, :event_notes)
end

#before filters
 def signed_in_user
 unless signed_in?
    store_location
   redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
   end
 end

def correct_org
  timeline_org = @timeline_event.sales_opportunity.user.organization
  @user = current_user
  if @user.organization_id == timeline_org.id
  else
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "You are not permitted to visit that page. Please create an account or sign in"
  end
 end
end
```

My timeline_event model:

```
class TimelineEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :sales_opportunity
validates :activity, presence: true 
validates :due_date, presence: true
validates :sales_opportunity_id, presence: true
end
```

I can only imagine this is some syntax error or other stupid error on my part, because I just can't see anything wrong with the code (it's identical to all other forms on my site). Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong here please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with @smathy as you indeed can explicitly pass a value to a `hidden_field` tag like you have done.

However, that's not even necessary because you are doing a circular assignment. By that I mean you are declaring `@sales_opportunity` and assigning it the value of `@timeline_event.sales_opportunity` in the `edit` action of your controller.

You then go into the view and try to assign `@timeline_event.sales_opportunity` back to `@sales_opportunity`. That's circular logic.

If the `sales_opportunity` for the `timeline_event` you are editing is already present, and you aren't wanting to allow the user to edit it, why include it in the form at all? Delete the `@sales_opportunity` instance variable from the `edit` action in the controller, and just remove the hidden field entirely from the view.

See if doing that makes it work as desired.

Comment: Thanks Rob - this did indeed solve the problem. I'd previously been using the same form for both adding a new timeline_event and editing the timeline_event, but now I'm using a Modal for adding a new one, this is no longer necessary. Your changes have solved the problem - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `form_for` field helpers don't work like that, they don't take a `:value` key in the options. Basically the name of the field **must** correspond to a method on the object you've passed into `form_for` (in your case `@timeline_event`), and that's where the form will get the value from.

If you want to provide your own field and value, then use the `_tag` family of helpers, eg.:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :name_of_field, @sales_opportunity.id %>
```

Or use `f.fields_for` to create a sub-field (usually in combination with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`)